# CSS element rule

Tags: html, css, coding-style, stylesheet

I have a min height rule on the bottom of this page for an element I can't find the rule to edit to save my life. I just need to reduce the space on the bottom of the site.

The website is http://www.lumivase.com/

The problem I am having exactly is shown in this screen shot

[image]

```
<?php global $options; foreach ($options as $value) { if (get_settings( $value['id'] ) === FALSE) { $$value['id'] = $value['std']; } else { $$value['id'] = get_settings( $value['id'] ); } } ?>

    </div>

</div>

<?php if ( $wp_prolific_footer_widgets == 'Yes' ) { ?>
<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/footer-widgets.php'); ?>
<?php } ?>

<div id="footer" class="clearfix">

    <div class="limit">
         <?php _e(""); ?> 

    </div>

</div>

<?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So what is the problem? Could not get it. Why do not you reduce the min-height if it is there?

Comment: I can't locate the code in the CSS anywhere or directly in the HTML

Comment: I have tried adding #element and .element to the css and even element and none of them work in registering in the css to change the rule listed above.

Comment: The issue is that the style is an inline one, means embedded within HTML. You need to find the source of this <div> to get rid of the issue.

Comment: It might be the last line in your HTML, don't look in CSS

Comment: I have inserted my footer php code above. I am not seeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to locate the wp_footer() function, in your php code. It seems the problem is located within that function, but you didn't posted it, so we can't tell you what to change.

Comment: Well it took me a little bit like a retard to figure it out but i removed <?php wp_footer(); ?> and it disappeared realizing it was redundant calling of the footer. So dumb of me, ty so much man.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have an empty div tag in your html with just some styles on it. Check your html normally towards the bottom to find the div.

Also it looks like you are using alot of inline styles which is not really the best practice. Try to keep all your styles in the css file.

Comment: Yep. It's the last element before the body close tag.

Comment: I have removed all the code between </div>

</div>

<?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body>

</html> and the problem still exists

Comment: above is my current footer code and it still shows the same inline rule, I can't locate this code anywhere. Please help?!

Comment: I was AFK when you posted the footer code but I'm glad you found it. Since the wp_footer function was the last code to be called it made sense to look there. Glad it all worked out.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your `<?php wp_footer(); ?>`. Without the code for this function it's hard to tell.

If however, you don't want to play around with the code / or are unfamiliar with the code within the `wp_footer()`, you can add this to your CSS files or as a `<style>` element at the top of your file:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body div:last-child{
        min-height:0; //Modify this to add the min-height you require
    }
</style>
```

If the `min-height` value is still not respected you can use the `!important` hack, though I would first recommend playing the the `wp_footer()` function.

Comment: it was calling for the same element that was already present once I deleted that line the problem disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure it will work but maybe you can try it with jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('div').last().css('min-height', '0');
});
```

but I still recommend you to search in your footer code and remove this manually